# Remote Blob Store implementation. How to get current SQL Server DB name?

Tags: remote-blob-storage, sql-server, external-blob-storage

We are trying to develop Remote Blob Store (next RBS) provider for SharePoint 2010 (SQL Server 2008). In EBS (External Blob Store which is deprecated now) there is possibility to take site collection ID where actual content is stored from parameters passed to EBS interface.

The question: is there any possibility to take SharePoint site collection ID, web application ID or at list SharePoint content database information where content came from inside BlobStore class implementation. Based on this data we have different scenarios of storing BLOBs. I understand that RBS is SQL Server technology but it's really important for us to know if we are able to get where content came from inside RBS provider implementation.

Thanks beforehand for any help,

-Petro

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you are going to find that in RBS.  The pointer/stub is stored inside of SQL.  You would have to grab that information from the DB to get at it from that level, not from RBS.  RBS doesn't care, it just needs to know how to link to the BLOB.